# How to make Material UI List to open just one List Item?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use a List from Material-UI in React, where lists also have nested items. I have a code like this:

```
<List>
    {this.state.categories.map(category => {
        return (
            <ListItem key={category.categoryID} 
                      primaryText={category.name}
                      nestedItems={[
                          category.subcategories.map(subcat => {
                              return (
                                  <ListItem key={subcat.subcatID}
                                            primaryText={subcat.name} />
                              )
                          })
                      ]} />
        )
    })}
</List>
```

Although, in its current form it works, it has the default settings of List, which means that I can expand multiple `ListItems` to see their `nestedItems`. But, I want to have something like an accordion behavior. Where the user can expand just one `ListItem` at a time to see its `nestedItems`. So, if one is already expanded and the user clicks to expand the other one, the first one that was already expanded should be closed, and the one that was newly pressed should be expanded. Any idea how to achieve this using the `List` element from Material UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using List, use `SelectableList` and define the ListItems in the same way. To control the open/close behaviour of `SelectableList` use property `open` with each main list items.

Check the last example of the this **[DOC](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/list)** page.

**Code:**

Define a value in state variable:

```
value: '';  //no list will be in open state initially
```

Define the value property with SelectableList:

```
<SelectableList value={this.state.value}>
    <ListItem

        value = {1}
        open = {this.state.value == 1? true: false}
        onClick = {() => this._click(1)}

        primaryText="Brendan Lim"
        primaryTogglesNestedList={true}

        nestedItems={[
            <ListItem
                value='a'
                primaryText="Grace Ng"
            />,
        ]}
    />
    <ListItem

        value = {2}
        open = {this.state.value == 2? true: false}
        onClick = {() => this._click(2)}

        primaryText="Brendan Lim"
        primaryTogglesNestedList={true}
        nestedItems={[
            <ListItem
                value='b'
                primaryText="Grace Ng"
            />,
        ]}
    />
</SelectableList>


_click(value){
   this.setState({value});
}
```

**Imp Points:**

1- Define onClick only on main ListItems, not on sub items.

2- Inside _onClick pass the same value that you defined with main ListItem.

3- Define open property only on main list items not on sub items.

4- Put the condition in open property if state value is same as the value of that list item then open that list and close all other list.

Comment: But this still makes it possible to expand as many items as I want.

Comment: ya, by default we can open any no of items but there is a property of list item `open` we can use that to control the open and closing behaviour, use that and open only one item at a time, it will work.

Comment: @typos check the updated answer, locally its working properly, let me know if you have any doubt :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to keep track of the `selectedItem` so then you only render its nested items. Something like:

```
<List>
  {this.state.categories.map(category =>
    <ListItem
      key={category.categoryID}
      primaryText={category.name}
      nestedItems={
        category.categoryID === selectedItem ? [
          category.subcategories.map(subcat =>
            <ListItem key={subcat.subcatID} primaryText={subcat.name} />
          ),
        ] : []
      }
    />
  )}
</List>
```

Comment: Where is `selectedItem`? I believe it is not a property of `List`?

Comment: You need to create it. Either as you component's `prop` or a `state` prop. So every time you click on an item, you update `selectedItem` value.

Comment: Thanks. But, I get an error message that I supply boolean value in `nestedItems`.

Comment: It works to some extend, but does not give the effect I was expecting.

Comment: Maybe `SelectableList` suits your needs then.

Comment: Yes it appears so. Mayank Shukla's answer was what I expected. Thanks once again.